# Binance node api connection issue

Tags: node.js, binance-api-client

I am encountering an issue with the Binance API Node Connector where I am getting inconsistent results. Sometimes I receive the correct output like `{ mins: 5, price: '61547.44293040', closeTime: 1709275080153 }`, but most of the time, I encounter an error indicated by ECONNRESET.
Code Snippet:
javascript

`   const { Spot } = require("@binance/connector");

```
 const apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
 const apiSecret = "YOUR_API_SECRET";
 const client = new Spot(apiKey, apiSecret);

 async function main() { 
 try {
 const result = await client.avgPrice('BTCUSDT');
 console.log(result.data);
 } catch (e) {
 console.log(e);
 main();
 }
 }

 main();
```

Error Message:
Error: read ECONNRESET
at Axios.request (D:\programming hero\Next-Level Web Dev\practice-project\bot\bottest\Server-Template\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:3877:41)
...
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'`